# Easy Left Join SQL Syntax

Tags: sql, left-join

New to SQL and want to complete a LEFT JOIN.

I have two seperate tables with the below code:

```
SELECT 
    StockCode, SalesOrder, SUM(OrderQty) 
FROM 
    dbo.IopSalesPerf
WHERE 
    dbo.IopSalesPerf.CustRequestDate BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2017-07-31' 
    AND EntrySystemTime = 1
    AND Warehouse = '01' 
    AND StockCode = '001013'
GROUP BY
    StockCode,SalesOrder
ORDER BY 
    StockCode ASC

SELECT 
    SalesOrder, SUM(NetSalesValue), SUM(QtyInvoiced)
FROM 
    ArTrnDetail
GROUP BY
    SalesOrder
```

I would like to LEFT JOIN the last table onto the first using `SalesOrder` as the joining column. Can anyone assist with the syntax?

Comment: Show us your attempted query!

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? (MySql, Oracle, Sql Server, PostreSQL,...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpliest way would be:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT StockCode,SalesOrder,sum(OrderQty) 
    FROM dbo.IopSalesPerf
    WHERE dbo.IopSalesPerf.CustRequestDate between '2017-07-01' and '2017-07-31' 
    and EntrySystemTime = 1 and Warehouse = '01' and StockCode = '001013'
    GROUP BY StockCode,SalesOrder
    Order BY StockCode ASc
) AS A
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT SalesOrder,sum(NetSalesValue),sum(QtyInvoiced)
    FROM ArTrnDetail
    Group by SalesOrder
) AS B
ON A.SalesOrder = B.SalesOrder
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, just needed to rename the calculation fields.  Much appreciated.